# GitHub branch source jenkins plugin - possible to skip/ignore some pull requests

Tags: jenkins, github, pull-request

I am using GitHub Branch Source plugin in Jenkins and have added the *Discover Pull Requests from Origin* behavior. However, it scans for ALL pull requests.

Is it possible to configure it such that it skips certain Pull Requests ? e.g. If Pull Request contains a specific word like "automated" then skip the build. I tried using Filter by name (with wildcard) but that does not seem to work for Pull Requests. Build get started as soon a Pull Request is opened.